# How to override a class method so that called instances also have the overridden functionality (in Python)?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance, methods

Let's say I wanted to override the `__str__` method of the `fractions.Fraction` class to give LaTeX output instead of standard string output.

This would be how I'd do it:

```py
from fractions import Fraction

class LatexFraction(Fraction):
    def __str__(self):
        return f"\\frac{{ {self.numerator} }} {{ {self.denominator} }}"
```

and it works great for simple applications.

However, when I want to actually do math with these fractions, the overridden method does not persist: The new objects are actually instances of the old `Fraction` class.

How do I change this behavior to automatically use the new class instead of the old one in methods like `__add__` or `__mul__`?

Comment: You need to override all the other methods so that they return `LatexFraction` instances instead of `Fraction` instances.

Comment: Since that's probably not feasible, subclassing isn't really the best way to solve the original problem. You should just define a new function that displays fractions using Latex formatting.

Comment: @Barmar this seems very redundant and not object-oriented. Is this really necessary?

Comment: @Barmar then I'll lose all the benefits of overriding the `__str__` method, like being able to directly use it in f-strings.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. The real solution is what JavaScript has done: the base classes are designed to be subclassable, so when they need to create new instances, they call the constructor of the instance instead of hard-coding their own constructor.

Comment: But since `Fraction` isn't designed this way, you can't force it to do that.

Comment: @Barmar thanks a lot, I think I'm going to just use the repr-string (with `!r` and a `re.sub` afterwards). Everything else just seems like too much work.